# Should I preload interstitial ads when my game starts?

Tags: android, memory-efficiency, admob

I just recently added interstitial ads to my game. I loaded my interstitial ads when the main game actually starts so it wouldn't take long to load after the user exits to the menu, but on profiling the memory usage, I realized that there are a lot of ad related allocations that are causing the gc to run wild. Is it that I should only request ads when I need them?

Comment: It sounds like you have profiling data showing you whether you can afford to preload them as you are right now. Next you need profiling data showing how much the situation is improved (or how much the delay is worsened) when you load ads just in time. Then you can make an evidence-based judgment about which strategy is more appropriate for your game's needs.

Comment: noted. thanks for the reply. I'll make an update on my next profiling session.